# Add space after comma when publishing an array meteor

Tags: meteor

When I publish and print `<p>{{profile.classes}}</p>` I get English,Maths,Science. I would like it to print out with **a space** after the class `English, Maths, Science`.

I imagine there is a simple way to do this? I'm using, `autoform` and `simpleschema` just incase that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from @ThiagoSckianta is almost correct except, you need to replace using regex to replace all occurrences. See this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

```
Template.NameOfYourController.helpers({
    profileClasses: function () {
        return (this.profile && this.profile.classes) ? 
            this.profile.classes.replace(/,/g, ', ') : '';
    }
});
```

Then, in your html:

```
<p>{{profileClasses}}</p>
```

**Update:**
If `profile.classes` is an array, then you do 'toString` before calling replace like this

```
Template.NameOfYourController.helpers({
    profileClasses: function () {
        var classes = (this.profile && this.profile.classes) ? this.profile.classes.toString() : ''; 
        return classes.replace(/,/g, ', ');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the suggestions. I've tried implementing these and none of them work. Is there an error in the suggested code?

Comment: @bp123 What did you get, when you used this helper? Any error in your browser console?

Comment: @bp123 So I assume `profile.classes` is an array. See my updated answer.

Comment: Now meteor is crashing, unexpected token with line return classes.replace(/,/g, ', ') : '';

Comment: @bp123 My bad, forgot to remove the ternary condition. Updated the answer.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a helper function.

Go to the .js file of your page, where the controller is defined, and paste the code below. Remember to substitute the name of your controller.

```
Template.NameOfYourController.helpers({
    profileClasses: function () {
        // Avoid a ReferenceError in case your subscription is not ready or the field is not set
        return (this.profile && this.profile.classes) ? 
            this.profile.classes.replace(/,/g, ', ') : '';
    }
});
```

Then, in your .html file, write:

```
<p>{{profileClasses}}</p>
```

Another option is to pass a parameter to your helper function:

```
Template.NameOfYourController.helpers({
    formatList: function (list) {
        return list ? list.replace(/,/g, ', ') : '';
    }
});
```

Then, in your html:

```
<p>{{formatList profile.classes}}</p>
```

[The Meteor tutorial is an interesting starting point to learn this.](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app)

[You can find more details about templates and helpers in this session of the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers)